# Trying to Play an Audio File on iPhone linked to QR Code

Tags: ios

For my dad's funeral I want to have a QR code displayed that people can scan and hear a voice message from my dad.  I have the mp3 saved in a google drive.  I created a QR code to link to that audio file.  On an andriod it works fine.  On an iphone, when I scan the QR code the page opens, but the file will not play.  I tried saving the audio file as a WAV and then the page opens and I get an error when trying to play the audio file.  Any ideas on what format an iphone WILL play?

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to [Ali's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90809/267133), I was able to successfully test this with

- iPhone,
- mp3 and
- Google Drive

*(Before you follow the steps, you can try it out right away with my sample QR-Code).*

1. In Google Drive, right-click on your audiofile and select "Get link"
2. Change from "Restricted" to "Anyone with the link"
3. Copy the link

   *you should get something like this:*

   `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x-dZI56A9rosWrDdi_9I3EARREIxruZZ/view?usp=sharing`
4. Change `file/d/` to `uc?export=open&id=`
5. Delete `/view?usp=sharing`

   Now it should look like this:

   `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=1x-dZI56A9rosWrDdi_9I3EARREIxruZZ`
6. Paste the Link into any QR-Code generator (Choose the URL option).

Scan the following QR-Code with your iPhone Camera and open it in Safari. Audio playback should start immediately.

[image: QR Code to Audiofile on Google Drive]